# Update locale specific file programmatically

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, locale

I need to read a locale specific properties file from a file path and need to modify the same and then need to save the file with Java.

For example, I have two Locale file a)LoginPage.properties and b)LoginPage_sv.properties in my "C" directory. Now through program I will tread the files according to the Locale specified in program. If user select SV(Swedish) then system will read LoginPage_sv.properties and if English LoginPage.properties. After reading the file I have to change few values against the keys and need to save the same in the file.

I found lots of solution to read the file but still unware how to **update the file**.

Comment: `prop.store(new FileOutputStream("LoginPage_sv.properties"), null);`

Comment: But how to determine the locale specific file. If user choose Sedish then LoginPage_sv.properties else LoginPage.properties. Can't use if else too bacause if tomorrow new local added I need to change my programm then

Comment: `"LoginPage_"+local+".properties"` , you need to know local string for this

Comment: LoginPage_"+Locale.GERMANY.getLanguage()+".properties
This can solve my issue and through properties file I can read the same from file location too. But is there any way to update through java ResourceBundle Package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LoginPage_"+Locale.GERMANY.getLanguage()+".properties This can solve my issue and through properties file I can read the same from file location too.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is tagged with java-ee, so I recommend to hold the properties in a database, if you have to change them.

You can use EJB + JPA to access read and modify the data.

Comment: It's a local file so can't store in database. Need to do it through programatically.Sorry for wrong tag